# Extjs drag panel to move window

Tags: javascript, extjs

[Window picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9RXb.jpg)

As we know, the window can be moved if you put your mouse pointer on the window title area(black area) and then drag and drop. However, if we put the mouse pointer into the panel (red area) drag and drop, window cannot be moved. 
SO if it is possible the drag the panel to move the window.

```
    var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    autoScroll: true,
    tbar: toolBar,
    items:[item1],
    simpleDrag : true,
    });

    var myWin = new Ext.Window({
        closeAction : 'hide',
        id: 'myWin',
        autoDestroy : true,
        title : 'TE Statistic',
        width : 860,
        height : 585,
        style : 'padding:5 5 5 5',
        modal : true,
        resizable : true,
        maximizable:true,
        layout: 'fit',
        autoScroll:true,
        items:[myPanel],
    })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an ExtJs window draggable by body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157249/how-to-make-an-extjs-window-draggable-by-body)

Comment: I have tried that method, as a result, the window size cannot be resized.

Comment: You don't forget `resizable: true`? This method work for me https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/33il

Comment: I am really appreciate your help. Your method is works fine. But my project is using Ext 3.2.1 version, function Ext.util.ComponentDragger is not defined in this version. What a awkward.

Comment: it was necessary to clarify the version in question). But I could guess by component creation way